# How can I decrease the font size of the showAlertDialog title?

Tags: webos

How can I decrease the font size of the showAlertDialog title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (dirty) way is to overwrite the .dialog-title class of the palm css file. But this affects all alert dialogs of your app.

```
.dialog-title {
font-size:5px !important;
```

}

A better way is to use your one dialog template with:

```
this.controller.showDialog({
       template: 'dialogs/sample-dialog',
       assistant: new SampleDialogAssistant(this),
       wisdom: randomLorem(),
       preventCancel:true
 });
```

See [Palm Developer Guide](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1838&Itemid=244#.showDialog) for more information.